# Null Text Node issue with xml.dom.minidom in Python

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

Environment: Python 2.6.5, Eclipse SDK 3.7.1, Pydev 2.3

I am trying to parse and change values in XML data in Python using `xml.dom.minidom` and I'm having an issue with blank text nodes.

When I parse an XML file into a DOM object and then convert it back to a string using `toxml()`, the closing "Description" tags get messed up after all the blank text nodes.

Does anyone know the problem is?

**Contents of issue.py**

```python
from xml.dom import minidom  
xml_dom_object = minidom.parse('news_shows.xml')  
main_node = xml_dom_object.getElementsByTagName('NewsShows')[0]  
xml_string = main_node.toxml()  
print xml_string
```

**Contents of news_shows.xml** (notice the two blank Text nodes)**:**

```
<NewsShows Planet="Earth" Language="English" Year="2012">
<NewsShow ShowName="The_Young_Turks">
 <Description Detail="Best_show_of_all_time_according_to_many">True</Description>
 <Description Detail="The_only_source_of_truth"></Description>
 <Description Detail="Three_hours_of_truth_per_day">True</Description>
</NewsShow>
<NewsShow ShowName="The_Rachel_Maddow_Show">
<Description Detail="Pretty_great_as_well">True</Description>
<Description Detail="Sucks_badly">False</Description>
<Description Detail="Conveys_more_information_than_TYT"></Description>
</NewsShow>
</NewsShows>
```

**Output of the script** (notice the 2 "Description" tags that are messed up)**:**

```
<NewsShows Language="English" Planet="Earth" Year="2012">
<NewsShow ShowName="The_Young_Turks">
 <Description Detail="Best_show_of_all_time_according_to_many">True</Description>
 <Description Detail="The_only_source_of_truth"/>
 <Description Detail="Three_hours_of_truth_per_day">True</Description>
</NewsShow>
<NewsShow ShowName="The_Rachel_Maddow_Show">
<Description Detail="Pretty_great_as_well">True</Description>
<Description Detail="Sucks_badly">False</Description>
<Description Detail="Conveys_more_information_than_TYT"/>
</NewsShow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this actually causing a problem somewhere? From all that I know about xml, the strings `<tag></tag>` and `<tag/>` are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks!!  It seems that minidom removes blank Text Nodes when it parses the XML (or something like that)..  I was trying to change the value of all Text Nodes, but the ones that were blank were getting skipped since minidom had removed them... I solved it by checking if a Text Node exists and if not, I create one with the new value and add it to the structure using createTextNode() and appendChild().

Answer (score 1):

Below is code snippet from source "python-3.2.3.amd64\Lib\xml\dom\minidom.py".

```py
def writexml(self, writer, indent="", addindent="", newl=""):
    # indent = current indentation
    # addindent = indentation to add to higher levels
    # newl = newline string
    writer.write(indent+"<" + self.tagName)

    attrs = self._get_attributes()
    a_names = sorted(attrs.keys())

    for a_name in a_names:
        writer.write(" %s=\"" % a_name)
        _write_data(writer, attrs[a_name].value)
        writer.write("\"")
    if self.childNodes:
        writer.write(">")
        if (len(self.childNodes) == 1 and
            self.childNodes[0].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE):
            self.childNodes[0].writexml(writer, '', '', '')
        else:
            writer.write(newl)
            for node in self.childNodes:
                node.writexml(writer, indent+addindent, addindent, newl)
            writer.write(indent)
        writer.write("</%s>%s" % (self.tagName, newl))
    else:
        writer.write("/>%s"%(newl))
```

According to the function, if the "self" variable (which is the node to be written into XML) has no "childNodes", the writer will write a self-closing tag.

Comment: @Sumeet Barai If you do not expect this, the only way is modified this source file and recompile.